# css media query for iPad only and not desktop with iPad like resolution

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS media query to target iPad and iPad only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271493/css-media-query-to-target-ipad-and-ipad-only)

I'm trying to target only with css iPads and iPads only, all the solutions I found were similar to this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="css/ipadStyleRV.css" />
```

but this targets iPad and screens with resolution 1024 x 768. I want to target ONLY iPads and not desktop screens.

Is there a way to do it ONLY with media queries?

Thank you

Comment: Deja Vu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271493/css-media-query-to-target-ipad-and-ipad-only

Comment: I have seen and tryed all these answers,they are all based on width and the problem is that the query returns true on desktops if the resolution is 1024x768!!but i need to target only Ipad...

Answer (score 0):

you can also check if the browser supports touch events with javascript and apply css based on that.