# Change Javascript Dynamically with Screen Width & Height for Responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress revolution slider with `tabs` under slider.

As these tabs are looks good on large resolution but not looks good on mobile and iPad. So I want to make it responsive for all devices.

Now I find out that this slider tabs width generate dynamically from Javascript.

This is tabs which need to be responsive. 
[image: Image Tabs]

I am not sure which attribute will make it responsive.

Please give some suggestion on it,

Thanks.

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">var htmlDiv = document.getElementById("rs-plugin-settings-inline-css"); var htmlDivCss="";
                        if(htmlDiv) {
                            htmlDiv.innerHTML = htmlDiv.innerHTML + htmlDivCss;
                        }else{
                            var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
                            htmlDiv.innerHTML = "<style>" + htmlDivCss + "</style>";
                            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(htmlDiv.childNodes[0]);
                        }
                    </script>
<div class="tp-bannertimer" style="height: 5px; background-color: rgba(68, 150, 57, 0.15);"></div>  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">var htmlDiv = document.getElementById("rs-plugin-settings-inline-css"); var htmlDivCss="";
                if(htmlDiv) {
                    htmlDiv.innerHTML = htmlDiv.innerHTML + htmlDivCss;
                }else{
                    var htmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    htmlDiv.innerHTML = "<style>" + htmlDivCss + "</style>";
                    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(htmlDiv.childNodes[0]);
                }
            </script>

<script type="text/javascript">


                        /******************************************
                -   PREPARE PLACEHOLDER FOR SLIDER  -
            ******************************************/

            var setREVStartSize=function(){
                try{var e=new Object,i=jQuery(window).width(),t=9999,r=0,n=0,l=0,f=0,s=0,h=0;
                    e.c = jQuery('#rev_slider_35_2');
                    e.gridwidth = [1170];
                    e.gridheight = [385];

                    e.sliderLayout = "auto";
                    if(e.responsiveLevels&&(jQuery.each(e.responsiveLevels,function(e,f){f>i&&(t=r=f,l=e),i>f&&f>r&&(r=f,n=e)}),t>r&&(l=n)),f=e.gridheight[l]||e.gridheight[0]||e.gridheight,s=e.gridwidth[l]||e.gridwidth[0]||e.gridwidth,h=i/s,h=h>1?1:h,f=Math.round(h*f),"fullscreen"==e.sliderLayout){var u=(e.c.width(),jQuery(window).height());if(void 0!=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer){var c=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer.split(",");if (c) jQuery.each(c,function(e,i){u=jQuery(i).length>0?u-jQuery(i).outerHeight(!0):u}),e.fullScreenOffset.split("%").length>1&&void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0?u-=jQuery(window).height()*parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0)/100:void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0&&(u-=parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0))}f=u}else void 0!=e.minHeight&&f<e.minHeight&&(f=e.minHeight);e.c.closest(".rev_slider_wrapper").css({height:f})

                }catch(d){console.log("Failure at Presize of Slider:"+d)}
            };

            setREVStartSize();

            var tpj=jQuery;
            tpj.noConflict();
            var revapi35;
            tpj(document).ready(function() {
                if(tpj("#rev_slider_35_2").revolution == undefined){
                    revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_35_2");
                }else{
                    revapi35 = tpj("#rev_slider_35_2").show().revolution({
                        sliderType:"standard",
jsFileLocation:"/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/",
                        sliderLayout:"auto",
                        dottedOverlay:"none",
                        delay:5000,
                        navigation: {
                            keyboardNavigation:"off",
                            keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                            mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                            mouseScrollReverse:"default",
                            onHoverStop:"on",
                            touch:{
                                touchenabled:"on",
                                swipe_threshold: 75,
                                swipe_min_touches: 1,
                                swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                                drag_block_vertical: false
                            }
                            ,
                            arrows: {
                                style:"hesperiden",
                                enable:true,
                                hide_onmobile:false,
                                hide_onleave:true,
                                hide_delay:200,
                                hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                                tmp:'',
                                left: {
                                    h_align:"left",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:20,
                                    v_offset:0
                                },
                                right: {
                                    h_align:"right",
                                    v_align:"center",
                                    h_offset:20,
                                    v_offset:0
                                }
                            }
                            ,
                            tabs: {
                                style:"hesperiden",
                                enable:true,
                                width:300,
                                height:75,
                                min_width:100,
                                wrapper_padding:5,
                                wrapper_color:"#e9e9e9",
                                wrapper_opacity:"0.05",
                                tmp:'<div class="tp-tab-content">  <span class="tp-tab-date">{{param1}}</span>  <span class="tp-tab-title">{{title}}</span></div><div class="tp-tab-image"></div>',
                                visibleAmount: 4,
                                hide_onmobile: true,
                                hide_under:800,
                                hide_onleave:false,
                                hide_delay:200,
                                direction:"horizontal",
                                span:true,
                                position:"outer-bottom",
                                space:8,
                                h_align:"center",
                                v_align:"bottom",
                                h_offset:10,
                                v_offset:20
                            }
                        },
                        visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                        gridwidth:1170,
                        gridheight:385,
                        lazyType:"none",
                        shadow:0,
                        spinner:"spinner3",
                        stopLoop:"on",
                        stopAfterLoops:1000,
                        stopAtSlide:1,
                        shuffle:"off",
                        autoHeight:"off",
                        hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                        hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                        hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                        hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                        debugMode:false,
                        fallbacks: {
                            simplifyAll:"on",
                            nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                            disableFocusListener:false,
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); /*ready*/
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CSS's media query?

Use this code for ipad:

```
@media (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { 
    /* Styles for ipad */
}
```

- [Example media queries for ipad and iphone](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)
- [Documentation From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- [Documentation From Web3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- [Using With Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)
- [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271493/css-media-query-to-target-ipad-and-ipad-only)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11909231)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Edited as you recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the edit ! I have no knowledge about javascript, but how does this code handle the new iPad Pro resolution?

Comment: Change the pixels, those I shown above, with the iPad Pro width-height. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549529/what-is-the-difference-between-screen-and-only-screen-in-media-queries) has some good explanations. You may google it such as: "ipad pro media query css"

Comment: Where should I add this code in Wordpress? I am still not sure about above code, Because as each tab width is 300px so for four tabs it becomes 1200px and not responsive.

Comment: Where will you add your js code? It must be placed before the items. You can manually calculate and place the exact pixels as styles of items.

Comment: As this is media css and my height and width for tabs decide from Javascript. So is it possible that it works

Comment: Media queries helps you to decide width & height before publishing. While the page is being displayed, you have no dynamic control. So you have to calculate height and width before you publish. You should read MDN documentation.