# Bootstrap: @media min-width AND max-width does not work on Ipad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the class "pad1" working on my Ipad (which has a width of 768px),

So I tried this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<style>
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width:991px){ 
    .pad1 {
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
}

</style>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row pad1">

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: orange;">

    AAAAA

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But the padding does not work, whereas if I remove the `and (max-width:991px)` part it works..

I also tried some other solution from a different post, like:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 767px) and (max-device-width: 991px) and (orientation:portrait) {

  .pad1 {
      margin-top: 150px;
  }
```

But it still not working, I am stuck here, and I absolutly need to limit the `max width` for this class, do you have any solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like a problem with specificity - what happens if you add a `!important` to the rule?

Comment: Try using just `(max-width:767px)`

Comment: @TiesonT. I just tried to add `!important` it does not work

Comment: @Swellar I tried with just `max-width:991px` and it does not work, so the problem comes from `max-width` property I guess

Comment: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad
Ipad all generation fall within the range `768` to `1024`

Comment: @aurelSon `(max-width:767px)` not `(max-width:991px)`

Comment: @Swellar Yeah I tried, also, does not work (but my Ipad is `768 px`, so I don't see why you suggest this solution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media query to target iPad and iPad only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271493/css-media-query-to-target-ipad-and-ipad-only)

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Yes indeed, the `@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)` works for me, thanks

Comment: Dont forget to add the meta tag for mobile device

Comment: @CedricGourville That is to say ? what it the purpose of this tag ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Change To :**

```
@media all and (min-device-width:767px) and (max-device-width:991px){ 
    .pad1 {
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
}
```

I hope ,help you.