# media query for desktop and iPad landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

So there are two divs as below:

```css
/*for ipad portrait and landscape*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .aclass {
        display: block;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
    }
    .bclass {
        display: none;
    }
}

/*for medium device*/
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 992px) 
and (max-width : 1200px) {
    .aclass {
        display: none;
    }
    .bclass {
        display: block;
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-xs aclass">div 1</div>
<div class="hidden-xs bclass">div 2</div>
```

I want `aclass` to be applied only in ipad and `bclass` to be applied in medium devices like desktop. The problem arises in Ipad landscape mode where `bclass` is applied because of the `min-width: 992px`, but I want `aclass` to be applied here. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `max-height`/`min-height` and/or `max-device-height`/`min-device-height` in the media queries and combine that with your existing queries.

Comment: device height is same for both ipad (in landscape mode) and desktop ie 768px. Can't differentiate.

Comment: There is another answer here, but I don't know if it still applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504571/5641669

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `and (orientation: landscape)`? This is a media query constraint that only enforces CSS the rules if the device is in landscape mode. Works the same for `orientation: portrait`

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it does not stop bclass to be applied

Comment: Then perhaps try @Johannes 's solution and use `min-device-height` and `max-device-height`. Combine then until they work.

Comment: device height is same for both ipad and desktop ie 768px. Can't differentiate.