# How to add CSS files for different platform devices?

Tags: css, html

I am developing mobile website in **Eclipse** tool(no plugins were used). It must support **android**,**blackberry**,**ios**,**windows** mobiles. I have five html files. Do i need to have seperate `CSS` files for each **device** & for each **html** files. Which would be optimistic method of adding `CSS` files?

And will all the 4 platform accept same set of codes or do i need to have any specific code/functions for different devices?

what is the `height` specifying format(i.e. `px`,`em`,`%`) to be used, so that webpage can get adjusted to different mobile screen sizes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect different device platforms using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037973/detect-different-device-platforms-using-css)

Comment: I think the question is *should* not *how*? I think you should attempt to write a webapp to be platform agnostic whenever possible and only make exceptions when you need to for compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be the reason for different stylesheets? if you use media queries with good break points you should be just fine using one stylesheet.

The optimum units to use would be em and %.

Comment: there's also rem now :\

Comment: You still have to use pixel fallbacks for rem which makes it a no-go for me at the moment. It is a much nicer way of doing things though.

Comment: Do you have any reason for wanting to use separate stylesheets? if you are happy that my answer answers you question then please accept :).

Comment: i don't know which is the optimistic way of using css. Now i used @media queries in CSS.